# Publish python project with imported modules

Tags: python, publishing

I would like to publish a python project, but i use modules in it like socket. How do i add to the project code that is not mine? Is that even legal?

Comment: Usually, you list them as "dependencies" -- though some modules (like `socket` come in the python standard library so they're pretty much always there.

Comment: It depends on the license of the code that is not yours. You may be allowed to distribute other code with your project under certain conditions (attribution, publishing your source code, ..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to add modules that are in the standard library. For other dependencies, you can

- test if the module is available (`try: import x except: error()`) and notify the user to install it or even automatically install it
- [package your program](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and [have pip install the dependencies for you](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)
- use [cx_freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) or similar to make a stand-alone package from your program that includes the modules

If you're on Windows, you could package it yourself with the minimal [Embedded Distribution](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution) (from Python 3.5).

See the [Python wiki on deployment](https://wiki.python.org/moin/deployment) for further reading.

Observe the licenses of your 3rd party modules.